# Rails /new path interpreted as ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a controller whose routes are defined as:

```
resources :items, except: [:new, :edit]
```

and the `new` and `edit` actions are not defined in the controller.

When I browse to `/items/new` I get an error from the database saying that the item was not found.

And the parameters contain `{"id"=>"new"}` from which I understand that the `new` part of the path is interpreted as the id.

How could I get the `/items/new` to fail routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use constraints on the `:id` segment of your routes.

If you know your `id` will always be a number for instance, try using:

```
resources :items, except: [:new, :edit], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
```

This will prevent anything that does not match the `/\d+/` regex (ie. one or several digits) to be considered as an `id` value, thus preventing the route to be matched for `/items/new`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it in your controller to rescue it from failing by rendering a view

```
 class ItemsController < ApplicationController
   rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

    def record_not_found
     render 'record_not_found'
     #do the other stuff
      true
    end
  end
```